# SEVERE error in Eclipse Web application Startup

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, struts2

I use tomcat. I am developing a web application using struts2, and I use eclipse as my IDE for development.

I get this error

```
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load bean: type:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory class:org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Lakshmanan/My%20Documents/My%20Dropbox/Final%20year%20project/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/projit1/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:29:132
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:208)
 at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:131)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
 at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
 at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
 at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3838)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4488)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/classloader/ReloadingClassLoader
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:198)
 ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.classloader.ReloadingClassLoader
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
 ... 28 more
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/projit1] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 07 19:38:41 GMT+05:30 2010]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@afae4a: defining beans [personCrud,companyCrud,projectCrud,discussionCrud]; root of factory hierarchy
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Prototype beans currently in creation]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Mar 7, 2010 7:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [XML bean definition resources currently being loaded]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
```

I am confused . Please help me in rectifying this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very likely missing struts2-core.jar on your classpath (the `c.o.x.u.c.ReloadingClassLoader` class which is not found is in struts2-core.jar).